# Inverse morphism of group object is iso

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, morphism

Let $C$ be a category with finite products (and a terminal object). We can then define group objects as tuples $(G, m, e, inv)$ by requiring that the usual diagrams commute.

Is it true that the morphism $inv : G \to G$ is always an isomorphism?

It is certainly true for e.g. $C = \mathrm{Set}$, $C=\mathrm{Grp}$, $C=\mathrm{Top}$.

I would, in fact like to prove that $inv \circ inv = 1_G$.
If it is true, the proof should be simple diagram chasing - but I have not been able to deduce the statement. Could you please provide a proof, hint, or reference?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the slickest proof went through the idea that $G$ is a group object if $Hom(-,G)$ is a functor $C^{op} \rightarrow Grp$. Export the proof to the same proof in ordinary groups.

Comment: @Chessanator Thanks, that seems to be quite easy from Yoneda. A diagram-chasing proof could still be interesting, but I will definitely not try to construct one :D

If you post your comment as an answer, I shall accept it.

Comment: I don't have the details ready to hand, and I don't have the free time at the moment to make it into a proper answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will show that $inv: G \to G$ is an isomorphism in our category $C$ by showing that $inv^2 = id$. That is, $inv$ composed with itself will be equal to the identity on $G$. If you wish to check that $inv$ is a group isomorphism (internal to $C$) you would of course need to check that it preserves the group structure (which it will).

Let's start by checking algebraically why applying $inv$ twice will be the identity, just for inspiration. So for the moment let us assume that $G$ is a group as usual in the category of sets. I will write $\star$ for the group multiplication, to make it explicit when it appears. For any $x \in G$ we have:
$$
x = ((x^{-1})^{-1} \star x^{-1}) \star x = (x^{-1})^{-1} \star (x^{-1} \star x) = (x^{-1})^{-1}.
$$
Next we translate this in terms of functions. We start with some $x \in G$ and send it to $((x^{-1})^{-1}, x^{-1}, x) \in G \times G \times G$. Then we obtain $(e, x)$ and $((x^{-1})^{-1}, e)$ in $G \times G$ by respectively multiplying the first two and last two coordinates. Applying the multiplication map again we get $x$ and $(x^{-1})^{-1}$ in $G$, which should be the same by associativity.

Now finally for the diagram.
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
G @>{\langle inv^2, inv, id \rangle}>> G \times G \times G @>{id \times m}>> G \times G\\
@. @V{m \times id}VV @VV{m}V \\
@. G \times G @>{m}>> G
\end{CD}
$$
This diagram has to commute, because the square is the diagram expressing associativity. So going via the bottom route, we have
$$
m \circ m \times id \circ \langle inv^2, inv, id \rangle =
m \circ \langle e, id \rangle =
id,
$$
where the first equality is due to the commutativity of the diagram for the inverse map (precomposed with $inv$), and the second equality is the commutativity of the diagram for the identity element. Similarly, going via the top route we find
$$
m \circ id \times m \circ \langle inv^2, inv, id \rangle =
m \circ \langle inv^2, e \rangle =
inv^2.
$$
Since these two routes commute, we conclude that $inv^2 = id$, as required.

Comment: Brilliant, this proof is much more elegant than I have expected!